# How do I make my app scroll past something covered by the keyboard

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have two textboxes at the bottom of the page on my app for Windows Phone 7.  When I click on the second to last textbox, it brings up the keyboard and lets me type in the textbox. So then, I want to type in the last textbox, so I try to flick up to scroll down to it, but it won't let me since I'm already at the end of the page!

So I have to either click the back key to close the keyboard or click on an empty part of the app. I tried making the margin on the bottom of the text box larger which allows you to scroll down more and click into the textbox on the bottom even when the keyboard is open, but then when you close it, there is extra space on the bottom.

Is there a non kludgy way to get around this? I feel like it should just move the whole app upward when you have the keyboard open so you can still scroll to the bottom!!!

Answer (score 2):

You'd probably be best to redesign the app/page.

Alternatively, put all the page contents into a ScrollViewer so you can scroll down to the second TextBox.
You could even try scrolling the second one into view when the first gets focus.

Answer (score 1):

"a non kludg" way to get around is to redesign the app. You got 2 options:

- move textboxes to the top of the page
- make a new page with the bottom of the page

[Great series about WP7 design](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/11/11/2th-of-10-make-sure-your-buttons-are-visible-even-when-the-keyboard-is-displayed.aspx)